# VBA: How to check IF a specific cell contains an image and then delete the image if it exists

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

In the sheet titled `Counter Party Select` , I'd like to check if cell `D2` contains and imagine. If the cell does indeed contain an image (picture), I'd like to delete that picture. The code that I'm trying to use fails on the line `Set thing = Sheets("Counter Party Select").Range("D2").Select`.

The error message is `Run-time error 4242. Object Required`. What code should I use?

```
Sub Logo_Fill()

    Dim myImage As Shape
    Dim thing As Object
    Set thing = Sheets("Counter Party Select").Range("D2").Select
    
    If TypeName(thing) = "Picture" Then
        Set myImage = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Picture 1")
        myImage.Delete
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Delete Picture From Cell

- The following is a solution that uses (calls) the `deletePictureFromCell` procedure.
- Instead of the cell objects used in your (valid) solution, `deletePictureFromCell` uses their addresses.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Logo_Fill()
    
    Const wsName As String = "Counter Party Select"
    Const CellAddress As String = "D2"
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' The workbook with this code.
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
    Dim pic As Picture
    
    deletePictureFromCell pic, ws, CellAddress

End Sub

Sub deletePictureFromCell(ByRef PictureObject As Picture, _
                          Optional Sheet As Worksheet, _
                          Optional ByVal CellAddress As String = "A1")
    
    If Sheet Is Nothing Then Set Sheet = ActiveSheet
    
    For Each PictureObject In Sheet.Pictures
        If PictureObject.TopLeftCell.Address(False, False) _
          = Replace(CellAddress, "$", "") Then
            PictureObject.Delete
            ' If only one picture per cell, this could increase efficiency:
            'Exit For ' No need to loop anymore.
        End If
    Next PictureObject
   
End Sub
```

### Your Code

- You can rewrite **your** code using the `With` statement.
- Note the dots (`.`): `.Unprotect`, `.Pictures` and `.Range("D2")`.
- It is not necessary to use `Application` in front of `Intersect`, although it **might** be good practice to remember that it is a **method** of the `Application` object, and not the `Workbook` object.

**Refactored**

```
Sub Logo_Fill2()

    Dim pic As Picture

    With Sheets("Counter Party Select")
        .Unprotect
        For Each pic In .Pictures
            If Not Intersect(pic.TopLeftCell, .Range("D2")) Is Nothing Then
                pic.Delete
            End If
        Next pic
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

As you want the value of the cell D2, you should use

```
Dim myImage As Shape
Dim thing As Variant
thing = Sheets("Counter Party Select").Range("D2").Value
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to do this using a for loop:

```
Sub Logo_Fill()

    Dim pic As Picture

    Sheets("Counter Party Select").Unprotect
    
    For Each pic In Sheets("Counter Party Select").Pictures
        If Not Application.Intersect(pic.TopLeftCell, Range("D2")) Is Nothing Then
            pic.Delete
        End If
    
    Next pic

End Sub
```

Comment: You haven't qualified `Range("D2")`. Here is an exercise to show when the code might fail: Select another sheet in the same workbook (not `Counter Party Select`). Now run the code from `VBE`. It will fail with the following message: `Run-time error '1004': Method 'Intersect' of object '_Application' failed`. The solution is to qualify the range: `Sheets("Counter Party Select").Range("D2")`.